# What packages do I use for the Free and Premium apps?

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play

I have a Premium (paid) app in Google Play.

I want to release a Free (with ads) version too, based on (almost) the same source code.

When I upload it to Google Play I get the following message:

```
You need to use a different package name because "com.brdgms.android" is already used by one of your other applications.
```

When I change the package name I get the following question:

```
The package definition in the manifest changed. Do you want to update your Launch Configuration(s)?
```

and regardless if I answer yes or now, I then get hundreds of errors for R.

I use Eclipse.

What should I do?

Comment: defined package in manifest should be same package name in package explorer.

Comment: Do I have to move any classes when I switch between compiling the Free and the Premium version?

Comment: I dont know. I just know for changing package name you can select package and press F2 button for renaming. then if package name in manifest not changed you should change it manually. excuse me, my English is weak.

Comment: Do you use Android studio? In this case you can change the ApplicationId in build.gradle, in this way physical path and R package too don't require any changes. In other case (with Eclipse for example) you need to change all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I turned the former application into a library, and created a new project which uses this library.

I spent a few hours on why android-support-v7-appcompat compatibility was included twice, and then excluded it from the new project's list of projects, and Java Build Path projects.

It is included by the library project.